# Windows Phone - PC communication in same network

Tags: windows-phone-7, networking, wifi, wcf-data-services, nat

I am trying to communicate a Windows Phone with a PC behind same wireless network and i am wondering if i can do it without a possible NAT block ?

Application at PC(Win7) side: hosting WCF Service on http://localhost:8080 - (say the internal IP is 192.168.2.2)

Application at WP side: accessing WCF Service hosted on http://192.168.2.2:8080

I was able to communicate those two when allowed port 8080 on windows firewall in my personal network. But when I've tried on a corporate network, WP couldn't access WCF Service.

Well, i think the reason was router firewall aka NAT. I am unsure if NAT is blocking certain packets coming from internal network peer to other internal network peer?

(IF that is not the case what else might be?)

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks for your interest

Comment: First check if they are in the same network then check if that port is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

There is NAT and there is the exact IP address you are using - both might be causing issues. Check with the person who configured the firewall. I am guessing the port is blocked or you are using a different IP assignment scheme on your corpnet.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but certains things remained unclear in my mind: 1. All the IP addresses i'am dealing with are virtual ip addresses - having 10.x.x.x scheme in the same subnet- what do you mean by exact IP addresses ? 2. The port on PC that i want to access is open, can there be port restrictions on routers?

Comment: Make sure you are 1) Putting the correct IP *in the app*. 2) Check the router configuration, yes, the port might be blocked there too.